# How to define route in phalcon

Tags: phalcon, phalcon-routing

I have controller named **GlossaryController** with 2 actions **indexAction** and **anotherAction** in view i have a directory glossary and **index.volt** file

i want to define a route with parameters for example 
*http://localhost/project/glossary/another/params* it should redirect me to indexAction with parameters

Comment: You mean to redirect you to anotherAction with parameters? "another" is in url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your routes.php file in app/config folder add this line:

```
$router->add("/glossary/another/{param1}/?{param2}", array(
    "controller" => "Glossary",
    "action"     => "another",
));
```

And your anotherAction method will be like:

```
public function anotherAction($param1, $param2 = 0) {
//some code
}
```

This way first param must be sent, second one is optional, you can add this way as much params as you like.

See official docs for various ways of routing:
https://olddocs.phalconphp.com/en/3.0.3/reference/routing.html